# Sending SAML response to application for testing purposes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-saml

I have to implement SAML Idp initiated flow for my project. I have used https://www.ssocircle.com/en/ and spring-saml to implement this. Now i want easy way to simulate SAML response from Idp in my project. I have captured SAML response ( xml document ) and my intent to provide that response directly to application ( while providing SAML response to application, i can modify it to add custom attributes which i need in my project). Is this possible ? I could not found any reference in internet. How should i proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone come across such a problem, try using https://capriza.github.io/samling/samling.html. I have successfully solve my problem with this. It offer adding custom attributes.